# eclipse plugin source

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext

I'm using eclipse application to run my dsl.
I want to add a feature that takes files from the running ui and do something.

how can i get the file directory of the plugin in runtime?

thanks,
dana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
myPlugin.getBundle().getLocation()
```

or

```java
URL pluginUrl = myPlugin.getBundle().getEntry("/");
pluginUrl = FileLocator.resolve(pluginUrl);
File pluginLocation = new File(pluginUrl.getFile);
```

Comment: ok, great but how do i get the plugin object?

Comment: Depends on what exactly do you need. If you are writing a plugin, you can use the instance of your plugin's activator class. You can also query the platform for other plugins.

Comment: I tried to get files from the plugin..
so i used the activator.getBundle().getLocation()
and it returns the path for the current place and not the "eclipse application" path

Comment: What do you mean by the current place? Does it not return the path to the location of the plugin? Which path do you need exactly?

Comment: If you need the location of the eclipse folder, you can try `Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL().getFile()`

Comment: thank you very much! i use the getInstanceLocation method.. 
you were very helpful!